# Reverse Function Array String

Tags: c, arrays, string

- Why is my reverse function not reversing my string back to Hello! when i am calling my function the second time?
- What could i change to use my function to reverse + dereverse my string multiple times?

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>

  void reverse(char arr[], int numberOfChars);

  int main()
  {
      char myString[] = "Hello!";
      int length = strlen(myString);

      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
          printf("%c", myString[i]);
      }
      printf("\n");

      reverse(myString, length);
      reverse(myString, length);

      getchar();
      return 0;
  }

  void reverse(char arr[], int numberOfChars)
  {
      for (int i = numberOfChars - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
          printf("%c", arr[i]);
      }
      getchar();
  }
  ```

Comment: you are not reversing a string, you are just printing in reverse order

Answer (score 5):

Because you never modify `arr[]` inside `reverse()`, you just print it in the order you iterate.

It should be something like:

```
void reverse(char *s, size_t length)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < length / 2; ++i)
  {
    const size_t tail = length - (i + 1);
    const char tmp = s[tail];
    s[tail] = s[i];
    s[i] = tmp;
  }
}
```

Also no weird `getchar()` call in  `reverse()`, that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reverse the words "Hello!", it is more convenient to define it as string and then use `reverse(myString.begin(), myString.end())` or`reverse(&myString[0], myString.length())`

The parameter of the function`reverse(p1, p2)` should be `reverse(first_position, last_position)`

Besides, if you really want to define the string as char, you should put them inside iteration and then reverse them one by one as @unwind said.

More details about the `reverse` function can be found at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same string the second time as well. Your function is void, you practically are doing nothing with the string itself, just printing the letters in reverse order. For what you want, you should save what you are doing in a variable and then return it, and maybe use a function to print separately.

Answer (score 0):

The argument (myString) to the reverse function is same in two times when you called from the main function. You are just printing the char in reverse format instead of reverse in sub module.